# Bizzare matplotlib behaviour in displaying images cast as floats

Tags: python, matplotlib

When a regular RGB image in range (0,255) is cast as float, then displayed by matplotlib, the image is displayed as negative. If it is cast as uint8, it displays correctly (of course). It caused me some trouble to figure out what was going on, because I accidentally cast one of images as float.

I am well aware that when cast as float, the image is expected to be in range (0,1), and sure enough, when divided by 255 the image displayed is correct. But, why would an image in range (0,255) that is cast as float displayed as negative? I would have expected either saturation (all white) or automatically inferred the range from the input (and thus correctly displayed)? If either of those expected things happened, I would have been able to debug my code quicker. I have included the required code to reproduce the behaviour. Does anyone have insight on why this happens?

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    a = np.random.randint(0,127,(200,400,3))
    b = np.random.randint(128,255,(200,400,3))
    img=np.concatenate((a,b)) # Top should be dark ; Bottom should be light
    plt.imshow(img) # Inverted
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(np.float64(img)) # Still Bad. Added to address sascha's comment
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(255-img) # Displayed Correctly
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(np.uint8(img)) # Displayed Correctly
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(img/255.0) # Displays correctly
```

Comment: Behaviour confirmed. Didn't believe you.

Comment: As noted by sascha below, my minimal example was not cast as float but as int64 as I used `np.randint()`. But I noticed the issue when I was working with real images cast as floats and the issue does persist even when it is cast as floats. I changed the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the sources, in `image.py`, in the `AxesImage` class (what `imshow` returns) a method `_get_unsampled_image` is called at some point in the drawing process. The relevant code starts on line 226 for me (matplotlib-1.5.3):

```
if A.dtype == np.uint8 and A.ndim == 3:
    im = _image.frombyte(A[yslice, xslice, :], 0)
    im.is_grayscale = False
else:
    if self._rgbacache is None:
    x = self.to_rgba(A, bytes=False)
    # Avoid side effects: to_rgba can return its argument                        
    # unchanged.                                                                 
    if np.may_share_memory(x, A):
       x = x.copy()
    # premultiply the colors                                                     
    x[..., 0:3] *= x[..., 3:4]
    x = (x * 255).astype(np.uint8)
    self._rgbacache = x
```

So the type and size of the input `A` get checked:

```
if A.dtype == np.uint8 and A.ndim == 3:
```

in which case there is no preprocessing. Otherwise, without checking the range of the input, you ultimately have a multiplication by 255 and a cast to `uint8`:

```
x = (x * 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

And we know what to expect if `x` is from 0 to 255 instead of 0 to 1:

```
In [1]: np.uint8(np.array([1,2,128,254,255])*255)
Out[1]: array([255, 254, 128,   2,   1], dtype=uint8)
```

So light becomes dark. That this inverts the image is probably not a planned behavior as I think you assume.

You can compare the values of `_rgbacache` in the object returned from `imshow` for each of your input cases to observe the result, e.g. `im._rbacache` where `im = plt.imshow(np.float64(img))`.

Comment: The behavior is not bizarre. The computation on the invalid but unchecked input still produced an output. In my opinion, you should just stop there: if the code performs some incorrect computation, shame on the programmers; if I gave input the docs didn't make any guarantees about and I didn't get what I expected, shame on me. You're free to file a bug or feature request if you feel there should be more checks.

Comment: You're right. There was an error on my part as the docs did not make any promises as to **how** such inputs would be processed. But now, thanks to your answer, I know the source of the behavior. I'm not sure if there should be a documentation entry about this processing or an additional check for the range to throw an warning/error though !

Comment: Actually I agree, it makes sense for there to be an error.

Comment: Just don't throw a cryptic error like many of the python-ported OpenCV functions ;) - [light-hearted joke... `cv2` is one of my favourite things to import]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on a wrong path here as you are claiming, that `np.random.randint()` should return an float-based array. **It does not!** ([docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html))

**This means**:

Your first plot is calling imshow with an **numpy-array of dtype=int64**. This is not allowed as seen [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)!

The only allowed dtypes for your dimensions are described as: ([see docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)):

```
MxNx3 – RGB (float or uint8 array)  # there are others
                                    #  -> this one applies to your dims!
```

The only valid calls to imshow in your example are number 3 and 4 (while 1 and 2 are invalid)!

Listing:

- `plt.imshow(img)` **not ok** as dtype=int64
- `plt.imshow(255-img)` **not ok** as dtype=int64
- `plt.imshow(np.uint8(img))` **ok** as dtype=uint8 (and compatible dims)
- `plt.imshow(img/255.0)` **ok** as dtype=float (and compatible dims)

**Remark:**

If this makes you nervous, you could checkout [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) which is by design a bit more cautious about the internal representation of images (during custom-modifications and the resulting types). The internal data-structures are still numpy-arrays!

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. You're right in everything you said. But, the minimal example I used was just to replicate what I saw with actual images. The first one is indeed cast as 'dtype=int64' as you said. But, the behavior persists even if it was cast as float64. I changed the code to show that.

Comment: @Prophecies **Your new example is still invalid**. Casting a numpy-array of dtype int64 with values in range [0,255] to a numpy-array of floats will still have the same range. As you said yourself: when using imshow with floats, a range in [0,1] is expected! (the case with dims (x,y) can be normalized and will be by default; your case (x,y,3) will not be normalized!)

Comment: That is right. It is invalid, but doing (255-img) is also still invalid but that displays correctly. I'd have been happy with a whited out image (as all values are >= 1), automatically adjusted to accommodate the input range (a la MATLAB) or even an error. Displaying Negatives doesn't make sense though! It displays correctly when I substract all values from 255, which is still invalid ! Hope this clarifies what I meant.

Comment: @Prophecies 255-img is totally ok. Again: img is uint8! (and even if it would not be: ```is also still invalid but that displays correctly``` is not very scientific... there have to be no rules if the input is wrong; some stuff works, other does not). If you don't want to play by matplotlib's rules, well... be prepared to run into pain. Regarding normalization: if you would stick to dims (x,y), this would be automatically done. But doing this with 3 channels is not that obvious and therefore not default or even possible (in matplotlib).

Comment: I feel like I'm not fully communicating this. I have posted the code, you can play with it. It's inverted when the range is (0,255) and is cast (invalid-ly) as floats.
`plt.imshow(np.float64(img))` will be displayed inverted. (I know this is invalid). But, `plt.imshow(np.float64(255-img))`will be displayed correctly (which is also invalid though)

Comment: @Prophecies Both versions of your code play well with what is documented in the docs! And your logic is flawed (the implication: that's wrong too, but this one is working; undefined input has undefined output in general; it might work sometimes, but sometimes it won't). I don't want to be rude, but i cannot help anymore here.

Comment: I would like to disagree with the statement that `There have to be no rules if input is wrong, some stuff works, other does not `. We should expect wrong things to throw error or modify it in predictable ways. Would you be happy if every time there was an divide by zero, it set your result to some random number?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125211/discussion-between-prophecies-and-sascha).

Comment: @Prophecies There are always limits. Check out an commercial LP-solver like Gurobi. And check the mailing-list what's happening to some people. It's like always a cost/use calculation what is handled explicitly in code.