# Converting all non-black pixels into one colour doesn't produce expected output

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing

I am trying to select non-black pixel and then colour them to black and the black pixels to white. I used a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52735231/how-to-select-all-non-black-pixels-in-a-numpy-array) provided on Stack Overflow but so far it isn't working for me.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


image = plt.imread('Perforated_carbon/faltu.png')
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
image_copy = image.copy()

black_pixels_mask = np.all(image == [0, 0, 0], axis=-1)

non_black_pixels_mask = ~black_pixels_mask
# or non_black_pixels_mask = np.any(image != [0, 0, 0], axis=-1)  

image_copy[black_pixels_mask] = [255, 255, 255]
image_copy[non_black_pixels_mask] = [0, 0, 0]

plt.imshow(image_copy)
plt.show()
```

**This is the image I am getting currently**

[image]

**What I would ideally like is this**

[image]

Additional information:

```
>>> image.shape
(256, 192, 3)
>>> image.dtype
dtype('float32')
>>> import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)
2.0.0
```

Comment: has `black_pixels_mask` the proper size you expect? Does it has 0 and 1?

Comment: Why not just use `black_pixels_mask` as your output image? Maybe it needs to be converted to a different type, but I don’t see the point in this indexing you do...

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, `plt.imshow(black_pixels_mask, cmap='Greys_r')` will do, IIUC.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing

```
black_pixels_mask = np.all(image == [0, 0, 0], axis=-1);
```

to

```
black_pixels_mask = np.all(image == [0, 0, 0], axis=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in matplotlib versions <2.2.0 there was no [normalization](https://github.com/Zac-HD/matplotlib/blob/7f976981913b3266ae91ccc901c3ed63a2a93e8d/lib/matplotlib/image.py#L629-L640) and any warnings when you passed an array to `imshow` that contained data out of expected range. So, you could get some unexpected results, like here: [Bizzare matplotlib behaviour in displaying images cast as floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925420/bizzare-matplotlib-behaviour-in-displaying-images-cast-as-floats)

If you update your matplotlib to version >=2.2.0, when running the code in the question, you will see the following warning:

```
Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).
```

and the produced image will be the one that you would want to get. So, my advice for you is to replace

```
image_copy[black_pixels_mask] = [255, 255, 255]
```

by

```
image_copy[black_pixels_mask] = [1, 1, 1]
```

and it would be also desirable to update matplotlib.

Here is related issue on GitHub: [`imshow` doesn't normalize the color range in RGB images](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9391), and a pull request: [Clip RGB data to valid range for `imshow`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10220).